# Different way of formed json in eventCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, calendar

I have a problem importing events from google calendar to a calendar plugin in jquery. The calendar is this one: http://www.vissit.com/projects/eventCalendar/

While getting data from a json in a server file, there is no problem. But, each time I try to do the same, generating the file dynamically, I get an error about json file. I tested the string and it is ok formed.

Do you know if I need to add any header or something before passing the string to the calendar? I am getting mad trying things, trying to create the file in server in php and asking for it from the webpage...

This is my example webpage:

```
<body id="responsiveDemo">  
<!--##############################################################################################-->
<div data-role="page" id="test" data-theme="e">

<div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
    <a href="#people" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
    <!--<a data-theme="e" href="#settings" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext"></a>-->
    <h1>SECCIÓN TEST</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">

    <hr />
<div class="container">

<script>

var event = "";
var i = 0;
var jsonFile = '[';


$.getJSON('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/...............@group.calendar.google.com/public/full?orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true&alt=json',function(data){
 $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, entry){
    if(i > 0){
        event += ',';   
    }
    event += '{'; 
    event += '"date":"'+ entry.gd$when[0].startTime.substring(0,10)+'",';
    event += '"type":"",';
    event += '"title":"'+ entry.title.$t.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '",';
    event += '"description":"",';
    event += '"url":"'+ entry.link[0].href.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"';
    event +='}';
    i++;
 });    
event += ']';
event = event.substring(36);
jsonFile = jsonFile + event;

console.log(jsonFile);
});


</script>
            <div id="eventCalendarHumanDate"></div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#eventCalendarHumanDate").eventCalendar({
                        'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/..............@group.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
                        eventsjson:jsonFile,

                        jsonDateFormat: 'human'  // 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
                    });
                });
            </script>           

</div>
 </div> <!-- /content -->
</div>
<!--##############################################################################################-->

</body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="eventCalendar/js/jquery.eventCalendar.js"></script>
```

An example file in php for retrieving events is:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/json');
echo '[';
$separator = "";
$days = 16;
echo '  { "date": "1314579600000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Test Last Year", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url":     "http://www.event3.com/" },';
echo '  { "date": "1377738000000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Test Next Year", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url":     "http://www.event3.com/" }';
echo ']';
?>
```

And this works fine. Maybe this fails because I deleted some events to make it sorter.

My json file once created by javascript:

```
[{"date":"2013-12-11","type":"","title":"Asesoría de Empleo para Jóvenes","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NHA0M2N1a20xZXBpdDJmdGVhcjRsaHM1ZzRfMjAxMzA5MThUMDk0NTAwWiA0OGsycjRsNm82MG5ibjJjdWc5cDBsdWs3Y0Bn"},{"date":"2013-12-13","type":"","title":"Capoeira - Encuentro","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=b2lqN2pidThzdmFqajV2dDI3MnY3bzBpcXNfMjAxMzEwMDRUMTUzMDAwWiA0OGsycjRsNm82MG5ibjJjdWc5cDBsdWs3Y0Bn"},{"date":"2013-12-13","type":"","title":"Reiki - Encuentro","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=b2drb3JtMW1obnJnaDZ2NWFob3ZkbXE3YjRfMjAxMzEwMDRUMTgwMDAwWiA0OGsycjRsNm82MG5ibjJjdWc5cDBsdWs3Y0Bn"},{"date":"2013-10-08","type":"","title":"Exposición de fotografía 'Angry Landscapes' de Gonzalo José Lago Amor","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=cXVtcWhibmwwMnVwNG4zcmsxMXRybzY5c2MgNDhrMnI0bDZvNjBuYm4yY3VnOXAwbHVrN2NAZw"},{"date":"2013-12-10","type":"","title":"Yoga - Taller","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=N2cyNnNwcDN1dHAza3A5NDhqZTUyMGsxOGNfMjAxMzExMDVUMTkzMDAwWiA0OGsycjRsNm82MG5ibjJjdWc5cDBsdWs3Y0Bn"},{"date":"2013-12-11","type":"","title":"Restauración de muebles - Taller","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=ZDRiOW04bGEwZGNqdTJqODl1OTNoNHJjajBfMjAxMzExMDZUMTg0NTAwWiA0OGsycjRsNm82MG5ibjJjdWc5cDBsdWs3Y0Bn"},{"date":"2013-12-11","type":"","title":"Coaching y PNL - Taller","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MGE3Mzd0bGxkOGtsbXZzOTJmZG90NW5kbmdfMjAxMzExMDZUMTkwMDAwWiA0OGsycjRsNm82MG5ibjJjdWc5cDBsdWs3Y0Bn"},{"date":"2013-12-12","type":"","title":"Reiki - Taller","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=aGd0bWFydm4wY2t1Y3J0cXJyajYwb21tMGtfMjAxMzExMDdUMTkwMDAwWiA0OGsycjRsNm82MG5ibjJjdWc5cDBsdWs3Y0Bn"},{"date":"2013-12-10","type":"","title":"Fiscalidad para asociaciones juveniles - Curso","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dXM4OG9vZmVuNnE4bjFvdHJ2Y2UzaDBvZjAgNDhrMnI0bDZvNjBuYm4yY3VnOXAwbHVrN2NAZw"},{"date":"2013-12-11","type":"","title":"Santander medieval","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MzU0YTY1MzZhbGg4YWk3bm1jNG1mcGxwcjQgNDhrMnI0bDZvNjBuYm4yY3VnOXAwbHVrN2NAZw"},{"date":"2013-12-11","type":"","title":"Taller de Iniciación a los palos del flamenco","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=cGJyMjc1OXNnZGRqcTAzbDBuOGY1Z2FqbWcgNDhrMnI0bDZvNjBuYm4yY3VnOXAwbHVrN2NAZw"},{"date":"2013-12-12","type":"","title":"Coaching y PNL – Taller","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NmRsbWRzN2o2Mzdwb2V0YTVsaWZtc2NvaWsgNDhrMnI0bDZvNjBuYm4yY3VnOXAwbHVrN2NAZw"},{"date":"2013-12-13","type":"","title":"Charla Historia de la Música...","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MWQycjN1OG5wNnFtNTQxbDFnbTJvam5tbzggNDhrMnI0bDZvNjBuYm4yY3VnOXAwbHVrN2NAZw"},{"date":"2013-12-14","type":"","title":"Finde Hazlo tu mismo","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=cDMzdmNwMm41dHNhZm5ucnJsMHE4dDJwaG9fMjAxMzEyMTQgNDhrMnI0bDZvNjBuYm4yY3VnOXAwbHVrN2NAZw"},{"date":"2013-12-16","type":"","title":"Fiscalidad para asociaciones juveniles - Curso","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=ZG9vcTdsbjF0azFvcDh0ZGIybm5vNGUxbmNfMjAxMzEyMTZUMTcwMDAwWiA0OGsycjRsNm82MG5ibjJjdWc5cDBsdWs3Y0Bn"},{"date":"2013-12-16","type":"","title":"Fiscalidad para asociaciones juveniles - Curso","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=ZG9vcTdsbjF0azFvcDh0ZGIybm5vNGUxbmNfMjAxMzEyMTZUMTcwMDAwWiA0OGsycjRsNm82MG5ibjJjdWc5cDBsdWs3Y0Bn"},{"date":"2013-12-17","type":"","title":"Fiscalidad para asociaciones juveniles - Curso","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=cjlnN21wMDVtMDcwN2hwdTFoN3R0bzBqY2sgNDhrMnI0bDZvNjBuYm4yY3VnOXAwbHVrN2NAZw"},{"date":"2013-12-18","type":"","title":"Restauración de muebles - Taller","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=b3M3ZnI1bWI4OGlxZTY0NGY1bDVwbDFrMDQgNDhrMnI0bDZvNjBuYm4yY3VnOXAwbHVrN2NAZw"},{"date":"2013-12-20","type":"","title":"Exposición \"La feminidad no impuesta\" (Augusta Aliseda)","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=OXMxdGZscWE4c2s4ZjM4amVidGVwdHQzbWsgNDhrMnI0bDZvNjBuYm4yY3VnOXAwbHVrN2NAZw"},{"date":"2013-12-25","type":"","title":"Navidad","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MWk1bTZkY3RudmwwNjNxbDExbW5oMzE4cWcgNDhrMnI0bDZvNjBuYm4yY3VnOXAwbHVrN2NAZw"},{"date":"2013-12-25","type":"","title":"Asesoría de Empleo para Jóvenes","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NHA0M2N1a20xZXBpdDJmdGVhcjRsaHM1ZzRfMjAxMzEyMjVUMTA0NTAwWiA0OGsycjRsNm82MG5ibjJjdWc5cDBsdWs3Y0Bn"},{"date":"2014-01-01","type":"","title":"Año nuevo","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=aDQ5cHU3a3A5YTV2YnI5OGIwdHUyMTFtNG8gNDhrMnI0bDZvNjBuYm4yY3VnOXAwbHVrN2NAZw"},{"date":"2014-01-06","type":"","title":"Reyes Magos","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dnNxZTdtYXJ0NTlkZHRsZWNybzdqbDluOG8gNDhrMnI0bDZvNjBuYm4yY3VnOXAwbHVrN2NAZw"},{"date":"2014-01-22","type":"","title":"Charla Historia de la música...","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=ZzEwcjNsbDcwazZ0ZThpMTByNDNwb2E0dWcgNDhrMnI0bDZvNjBuYm4yY3VnOXAwbHVrN2NAZw"},{"date":"2014-04-17","type":"","title":"Jueves Santo","description":"","url":"http://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NG8zdjgzaWlhbGYwNHQ4a2U5YzVtbWRibDQgNDhrMnI0bDZvNjBuYm4yY3VnOXAwbHVrN2NAZw"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question, I stumbled upon it while reasearching.
From what is see there is an error in your output:

```
[{"date":"2013-12-11","type":"","title":"Asesoría de Empleo para Jóvenes","description":"","url":....
```

Data should be 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' whilst yours is 'YYYY-MM-DD'
so

```
[{"date":"2013-12-11 23:59:00","type":"","title":"Asesoría de Empleo para Jóvenes","description":"","url":....
```

should work